# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n4^n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I cannot solve the following exercise. Compute, if convergent, the sum of the series 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n4^n}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove convergence you can apply the root test or the ratio test or a comparison test to a similar looking series that you know converges.

The series does indeed converge.  What is the sum?

Do you know this Taylor series?

$ln(1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n}$

Answer (score 6):

Consider that the derivative of 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}n
$$
is the geometric series.

Comment: Old tricks never fail LutzL :D

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\frac{1}{n4^n} \leq \frac{1}{4^n}$ (for $n \geq 1$). Therefore:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n4^n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n 
$$

The right hand side is a geometrical series with $a^0=1/4<1$, which converges. By comparison, the original series converges as well.

Comment: the last equal sign is highly confusing

Comment: Ok, and what about the sum of the series $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n4^n}$?

Comment: I'm afraid that this doesn't address the question. The problem is to compute the sum. (I didn't downvote btw).